# How to translate admin interface in Drupal Commerce Kickstart?

Tags: i18n-l10n, commerce

I have translated my site in Japanese. But it is not translating all the content. I want to translate all the strings available on the site, including admin panel.

I searched for the string in the translate interface, but I couldn't find it. I used [Translation template extractor](https://www.drupal.org/project/potx) to search the strings. But this thing also didn't help me.

Please tell me how to change the admin side text?

Here's the image showing what kind of strings I want to change :

[image]

Comment: Have you searched for these strings in the commerce code? Are they wrapped in t() functions to make them translatable?

Comment: Will you please tell me in which file should I search?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did a search on my computer, I found product.html which contains the text you were looking for:

```
  <header id="header">
<h1>Help on products</h1>
<p>Each product has both a display and can have many variations (size, color, etc). This page lists all of the products grouped by display.</p>
```

```
<p>To see the variations of a product, click on â€œQuick Edit.â€ Using bulk updates (located at the bottom of the page) more than one product can have various actions applied.</p>

<h2>More Information</h2>

<ul>
  <li><a href="http://www.drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/product-management-overview">Product Management Overview</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/choosing-between-page-or-variation">Choosing between Products and Product Variations</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.drupalcommerce.org/commerce-kickstart-2/adding-new-product">Adding a New Product</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-attributes-variations">What are Product attributes and variations?</a></li>
  <li><a href="http://www.drupalcommerce.org/user-guide/product-displays">What are Product Node Displays?</a></li>
</ul>
```